# Detecting usage of Googles chromecast service within application

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, chromecast

I am trying to detect the usage of googles chromecast service within a library. Does anybody found a way to accomplish this? Detecting if the iOS device is currently streaming to an AppleTv is possible via:

```
UIScreen.didConnectNotification, UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification
```

But when ann App is casting to chromecast, both of these notifications are not fired.

Comment: If this is for detecting a new screen for device connection then it means there's a bug if the notifications are not fired. Please be noted that connection notifications are not sent for screens that are already present when the application is launched. Please check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617826-didconnectnotification) for more details.

Comment: @jess The problem is when you cast content to chromecast this is not being recognized as a new screen...

Comment: Xcode 10 Warning: If developing using Xcode 10 and targeting iOS devices running iOS 12 or higher, the "Access WiFi Information" capability is required in order to discover and connect to Cast devices from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/ Are you sure you put GCKCastContext and delegates right in the places?

Comment: I do not have the cast framework, and I do not want to use it. I just wat to detect if streaming to a cast device is happening or not...

Comment: without delegate methods, I think is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Using the USB-C port to connect the iPad to an external display for creative tasks. This is a feature that few people know already exists on all iOS devices.

With this small amount of code, you can listen for the connection/disconnection of displays and set up a separate window and view controller hierarchy for the external display to augment your app’s main content.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // For demo purposes. We're just showing a string description
    // of each UIScreen object on each screen's view controller
    @IBOutlet var screenLabel: UILabel!

    static func makeFromStoryboard() -> ViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", 
                            bundle: nil)
            .instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    // The main window shown on the device's display
    // The main storyboard will set this up automatically
    var window: UIWindow?

    // References to our windows that we're creating
    var windowsForScreens = [UIScreen: UIWindow]()

    // Create our view controller and add text to our test label
    private func addViewController(to window: UIWindow, text: String) {
        let vc = ViewController.makeFromStoryboard()

        // When we need to finish loading the view before accessing
        // the label outlet on the view controller
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
        vc.screenLabel.text = text

        window.rootViewController = vc
    }

    // Create and set up a new window with our view controller as the root
    private func setupWindow(for screen: UIScreen) {
        let window = UIWindow()
        addViewController(to: window, text: String(describing: screen))
        window.screen = screen
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        windowsForScreens[screen] = window
    }

    // Hide the window and remove our reference to it so it will be deallocated
    private func tearDownWindow(for screen: UIScreen) {
        guard let window = windowsForScreens[screen] else { return }
        window.isHidden = true
        windowsForScreens[screen] = nil
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
        ) -> Bool {

        // Set up the device's main screen UI
        addViewController(to: window!, text: String(describing: UIScreen.main))

        // We need to set up the other screens that are already connected
        let otherScreens = UIScreen.screens.filter { $0 != UIScreen.main }
        otherScreens.forEach { (screen) in
            setupWindow(for: screen)
        }

        // Listen for the screen connection notification
        // then set up the new window and attach it to the screen
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(forName: UIScreen.didConnectNotification, 
                         object: nil, 
                         queue: .main) { (notification) in

                            // UIKit is nice enough to hand us the screen object 
                            // that represents the newly connected display
                            let newScreen = notification.object as! UIScreen

                            self.setupWindow(for: newScreen)
        }

        // Listen for the screen disconnection notification.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification, 
                                               object: nil, 
                                               queue: .main) { (notification) in

                                                let newScreen = notification.object as! UIScreen
                                                self.tearDownWindow(for: newScreen)
        }

        return true
    }
}
```